# How can I proxy_pass all addresses after a location / with nginx?

Tags: nginx, node.js, proxypass

I'm running a node.js application called [serve](https://github.com/zeit/serve) that shows the files and folders from a specific path of my computer on a webpage:

[image]

This application works fine by itself and I see no error messages while trying to access folders. However, when I try to make it run with `nginx` on the location `/page/`, I'm not capable of seeing the contents of any files or folders and I get a `404 Not Found` error if I try to access them. I'm using the following `nginx.conf` file:

```
events {}

http {
    server {

        listen 80;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;

        location /page/ {
             proxy_pass http://localhost:8070/;
        }

    }
}
```

And the error message that I see is the following:

[image]

Apparently, the page is redirected to `localhost/a` and not `localhost/page/a` when I try to access the folder `a`. What am I missing here? Do I need to use a different structure to redirect everything from an application running on a specific port to a specific location (like `/page`)?

Comment: Try without the trailing slash `proxy_pass http://localhost:8070`.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz It didn't work without the trailing slash as well... Actually it doesn't even load the first page without it.

Comment: So `http://localhost/page/` loads correctly, but all the links on that page do not resolve? What do the links on that page look like?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I've updated the question posting the error message and the address that I see...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try access http://127.0.0.1 in browser and see if this works? The server_name directive is matches the HTTP host header as it is and does not rely on DNS resolution.  In case this works and you want to access with http://localhost, please change the server_name directive with localhost instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: It doesn't work either if I use `http://127.0.0.1:8070` or `http://localhost:8070` . I've tried making them match on `nginx.conf` too but it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

[The expression "*the server redirects*", when in the context of HTTP usually means "*the server sends a 30x response*", so your question may be a little misleading.]

The problem doesn't seem to be **nginx**, but **serve**: an application being proxied, must know how to generate HTML links correctly. In particular it must know:

- What is the hostname and port of the proxy server. This can usually be conveyed in a `Forward` header:

  ```
  proxy_set_header Forwarded $proxy_add_forwarded;
  ```
- What is the path to the application. This usually can be configured in the application.

In your case **serve** probably uses absolute URIs, even if it is not deployed on the root of your website. You can mitigate the problem, by instructing **nginx** to modify the returned pages:

```
location /page/ {
    sub_filter 'href="/' 'href="/page/';
    sub_filter 'src="/' 'src="/page/';
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8070/;
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:8070/ http://$server_name/page/
}
```

There is no guarantee though, that these expression will rewrite all URLs.

**Remark**: `server_name` in your config should be a domain name, not IP address. Put `localhost` instead.